# Unable to cast from DerivedT<Derived2T> to BaseT<base2T>

Tags: c#, .net, generics, .net-4.0, variance

I have those classes, an implementation of active record pattern:

```
public abstract class RecordCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T> where T : Record
public abstract class Record : INotifyPropertyChanged
```

every time i want to define a row of a database (ie a Contact), I create a new record class, like:

```
public class Contact : Record
```

and a collection of row of database (ie Contacts) as:

```
public class ContactCollection : RecordCollection<Contact>
```

but after that i can't use generic for contain a record colletcion:

```
ContactCollection contColl = new ContactCollection(databaseman dbMan);
contColl.Load();

RecordCollection<Record> recordColl = contColl;
```

it give me "Cannot implicitly convert type ContactCollection  to >". Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You're not casting.... You're just converting

Comment: I must use Converter<in TInput, out TOutput>?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This casting is not permitted simply because this could happen:

```
public class AnotherTypeOfContact: Record {}
```

Now we could do:

```
recordColl.Add(new AnotherTpyeOfContact()) //runtime exception as no conversion between AnotherTypeOfContact and Contact
```

This is what is called *covariance* and *contravariance* ([read more here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx)) between generic types. For this to work, `contColl` must implement a "out" only interface, which it doesn't. By this I mean that for type safety to be preserved, `contColl` can not allow to add items (more formally, `T` can only be the return type of a method)

Note that in arrays this *is* allowed, but its a broken covariance, which is unfortunate: [more here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/17/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-two-array-covariance.aspx)

Comment: So i must refactor and get an IContactCollection interface (IRecordCollection is not applicable, as i understand) with out parameter?  ContactCollection : IContactCollection, 
and IContactCollection : RecorCollection<out Contact>

Comment: If all you want is to enumerate the collection take advantage of `IEnumerable<T>` which is contravariant in T and implemented by `ObservableCollection`

Comment: No, i must have acces to some properties of RecordCollection, not only the observablecollection. I must change approach if i want this feature. Thanks for the reply.